# No 'id' member found on type 'PackingList.Models.Reis' : UWP (Windows 10 app)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services, uwp

```
public sealed partial class Login : Page
    {
        public MobileServiceClient client = App.MobileService;
        public IMobileServiceTable<Reis> reisTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Reis>();


        public Login()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Define a member variable for storing the signed-in user. 
        private MobileServiceUser user;

        // Define a method that performs the authentication process
        // using a Facebook sign-in. 
        private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
        {
            string message;
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                // Change 'MobileService' to the name of your MobileServiceClient instance.
                // Sign-in using Facebook authentication.
                user = await App.MobileService
                    .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
                message =
                    string.Format("You are now signed in - {0}", user.UserId);

                success = true;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                message = "You must log in. Login Required";
            }

            var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
            dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
            return success;
        }

        private async void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Login the user and then load data from the mobile app.
            if (await AuthenticateAsync())
            {
                Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

                ButtonLogin.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            }
        }


    }
```

An error is thrown on the "public IMobileServiceTable reisTable" line of the code, No 'id' member found on type 'PackingList.Models.Reis'.

This is our Reis class:

```
public class Reis
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="userID")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "departureDate")]
        public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "location")]
        public String Location { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "items")]
        List<ReisItem> ReisItems { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "taken")]
        List<Taak> Taken { get; set; }
}
```

I tried searching some examples or solutions online but couldn't find hard evidence of what we were doing wrong and where. Our azure service (DB online) gives the following error :

[image: Azure DB Error]

We have no idea where our fault is.

Comment: Looks like your table contains two child tables (ReisItem and Taak) via list properties.  Assuming that GetTable is smart enough to deal with that, have you set up your child tables with the appropriate relationship to the Reis table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mobile service client SDK currently requires your model to have a property (JSON property) named Id (id, Id or ID), which the object above does not have.

Adding that property to the type should resolve that issue.